# SMS Sending Using Java Without GSM Modem

Tags: java, sms

It might sound Weird But I want to send SMS using JAVA wthout accessing any GSM modem, is that Possible, I have used Mail serve APi. My idea is is there any mail sevrver which is freely hosted that we can access and Send sms Anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried http://www.mobile-sender.com/?

There are a lot of this kind of service on the internet.

http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=free+sms+online&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: hwy Partick That was good application though appreciate ypur effor, but I require to write a code for it

Comment: Have a look at jaxb answer with "clickatell"

Comment: Hi Patrich Can you suggest me an apprpriate link to Look for, As I am not getting anything relevant in net

Comment: Clickatel, Is not  freelly hosted Gateway, They also seems to charge to use their API

Answer (score 0):

If you want java/SOAP APIs and you are doing it for enterprise project 
[clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/) is a good option.

Benefits are **you can write a code in Java** and  **you can track the SMS status.** :)

Either you can use Java APIs or you can use HTTP/S APIs available which are pretty easy to use. Here is [APIs list.](http://www.clickatell.com/developers/clickatell_api.php?cid=185290)